# Selecting a form which is in an iframe using jQuery

Tags: jquery-ui, forms, iframe

I have a form inside an iframe which is inside a jQuery UI dialog box.  The form contains a file input type.  The jQuery UI dialog contains an Upload button.  When this button is clicked, I would like to programmatically call the submit method.  My question is how I could select the form which is in a iframe using jQuery.  The following code should clarify the picture:

```
<div id="upload_file_picker_dlg" title="Upload file">        
    <iframe id="upload_file_iframe" src="/frame_src_url" frameborder=0 width=100% scrolling=no></iframe>
</div>
```

frame_src_url contains:

```
<form action="/UploadTaxTable" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="upload-form">            
<p>Select a file to be uploaded:</p>
<p>
    <input type="file" name="datafile" size="60">
</p>
```

The jQueryUI dialog box javascript code:

```
$('#upload_file_picker_dlg').dialog({
    ...
    buttons: {
        'Close': function() { 
            $(this).dialog('close'); 
        },
        'Upload': function() {              
            $('#upload-form').submit(); //question is related to this line
            $(this).dialog('close'); 
        }
    },
    ....
});
```

From the javascript code snippet above, how can I select the form with id **upload-form** that is in the iframe whose id is **upload_file_iframe** ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Accessing an element inside an iframe is tricky.
You should use the following syntax:

```
$('#iframeID').contents().find('#upload-form').submit();
```

where 'iframeID' is obviously an ID you've given to the iframe.

Hope it is correct!

Comment: Yep, that's correct.  I posted my answer at the same you did.  But your answer is 100% correct.  I selected your answer and vote up on your answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is:

```
$('#upload_file_iframe').contents().find('#upload-form').submit();
```

which I learned from http://simple.procoding.net/2008/03/21/how-to-access-iframe-in-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head I'd say you might have to add the logic to the file where the iframe source is from.

Comment: Maybe that would work, but I shouldn't have to.  I just need to know a jQuery selector that selects a form (or id in general) that's inside an iframe.