# Select iframe using Python + Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, iframe, css-selectors

So, I was absolutely baffled as to how to do this in Selenium, and couldn't find the answer anywhere, so I'm sharing my experience.

I was trying to select an iframe and having no luck (or not repeatably anyway). The HTML is:

```
<iframe id="upload_file_frame" width="100%" height="465px" frameborder="0" framemargin="0" name="upload_file_frame" src="/blah/import/">
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="import_devices">
            <div class="import_type">
                <a class="secondary_button" href="/blah/blah/?source=blah">
                    <div class="import_choice_image">
                        <img alt="blah" src="/public/images/blah/import/blah.png">
                    </div>
                    <div class="import_choice_text">Blah Blah</div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The Python code (using the selenium library) was trying to find this iframe using this:

```
    @timed(650)
def test_pedometer(self):
    sel = self.selenium
    ...
    time.sleep(10)
    for i in range(5):
        try:
            if sel.select_frame("css=#upload_file_frame"): break
        except: pass
        time.sleep(10)
    else: self.fail("Cannot find upload_file_frame, the iframe for the device upload image buttons")
```

Repeated fails with every combination of Selenium commands I could find.

The occasional success would not be reproducible, so perhaps it was some sort of race condition or something? Never did find the right way to get it in selenium proper.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What finally worked for me was:

```
        sel.run_script("$('#upload_file_frame').contents().find('img[alt=\"Humana\"]').click();")
```

Basically, don't use selenium to find the link in the iframe and click on it; use jQuery.  Selenium has the capability to run an arbitrary piece of javascript apparently (this is python-selenium, I am guessing the original selenium command is runScript or something), and once I can use jQuery I can do something like this: [Selecting a form which is in an iframe using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953436/selecting-a-form-which-is-in-an-iframe-using-jquery)

Comment: You'd be better off using Selenium's getEval command (probably "get_eval" in the Python bindings) instead of its runScript command.  getEval won't return until the JavaScript code completes, whereas runScript simple inserts a <SCRIPT> element and returns, resulting in the browser running the JavaScript code **after** the call returns.

Comment: what exactly is `sel.run_script`? I can find no mention of this function in the docs or with google. While this may have worked for you, its a poor answer because you dont explain what `self.selenium` is or how to get `run_script` That said, driver.execute_script worked for me

Comment: Well, to be honest, it was five years ago, I have no idea by now.  Glad that driver.execute_script worked for you, though, good that you posted that here for the future readers.

Answer (score 100):

This worked for me with Python (v. 2.7), webdriver & Selenium when testing with iframes and trying to insert data within an iframe:

```
self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

## Give time for iframe to load ##
time.sleep(3)
## You have to switch to the iframe like so: ##
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))
## Insert text via xpath ##
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/p")
elem.send_keys("Lorem Ipsum")
## Switch back to the "default content" (that is, out of the iframes) ##
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Comment: Somehow the WebDriver finds the elements into the iframe when searching with xpath. I've tried finding elements by CSS, ID but it always gave me an error of not existing element (timeout failure actually because I used the waitForElement command). I didn't think searching element by xpath would make the difference, but I fortunately gave it a try when I was running out of ideas. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Especially handy when working with iframes that seem to have names and URLs that are being generated dynamically. Really useful, thank you

Answer (score 30):

If `iframe` is dynamic node, it's also possible to wait for `iframe` appearence explicitly and then switch to it using [`ExpectedConditions`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it):

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(URL)
wait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it("iframe_name_or_id"))
```

If `iframe` doesn't have `@id` or `@name` it can be found as common WebElement using `driver.find_element_by_xpath()`, `driver.find_element_by_tag_name()`, etc..:

```
wait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@class='iframe_class']")))
```

To switch back from `iframe`:

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Comment: This is probably the best solution for switching to frame but [frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/_modules/selenium/webdriver/support/expected_conditions.html#frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it) expects either a tuple `(By.ID,"frameID")` or WebElement, not plain string.

Answer (score 8):

You don't need to use JavascriptExecutor.  All you needed to do was switch into the frame and then switch back out, like so:

```
// do stuff on main window
driver.switch_to.frame(frame_reference)
// then do stuff in the frame
driver.switch_to.default_content()
// then do stuff on main window again
```

As long as you are careful with this, you will never have a problem.   The only time I always use a JavascriptExecutor is to get window focus since I think using Javascript is more reliable in that case.

Answer (score 4):

To shift [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491)'s focus within the `<iframe>` you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `ID`:

  ```
  driver.switch_to.frame("upload_file_frame")
  ```
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe#upload_file_frame"))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//iframe[@id='upload_file_frame']"))
  ```

---

Ideally, you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it* and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `ID`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID,"upload_file_frame")))
  ```
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe#upload_file_frame")))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@id='upload_file_frame']")))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
   from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
   from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
   from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)
- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)

Answer (score 3):

Selenium's selectFrame command accepts all the standard locators like `css=`, but it also has a an extra set of locators that work specifically with FRAME and IFRAME elements.

As [the doc](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/1.0/reference.html#selectFrame) says:

> **selectFrame ( locator )**  Selects a frame within the current window.
>   (You may invoke this command multiple times to select nested frames.)
>   To select the parent frame, use "relative=parent" as a locator; to
>   select the top frame, use "relative=top". You can also select a frame
>   by its 0-based index number; select the first frame with "index=0", or
>   the third frame with "index=2".
>
> You may also use a DOM expression to identify the frame you want
>   directly, like this: `dom=frames["main"].frames["subframe"]`
>
> Arguments: locator - an element locator identifying a frame or iframe

In general, you'll have better luck using the specialized locators, especially if you establish the right context first (*e.g.*, `select_frame("relative=top"); select_frame("id=upload_file_frame");`).

Comment: Yeah, selectFrame didn't work for me.  Doesn't mean it won't work for anyone, but I found it to actually select the frame about one time in 5.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this simple code to look for the iframe using xpath

sample use
set_iframe("/html/body/div[2]/table/")

```
def set_iframe(xpath):
    print('set_iframe')
    driver.switch_to.default_content()
    seq = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')
    for x in range(0, len(seq)):
        driver.switch_to.default_content()
        print ("iframe-"+str(x))
        try:
            driver.switch_to.frame(int(x))
            driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
            return str(x)
        except:
            continue
```