# How to select the Facebook share frame with webdriver and python

Tags: python, webdriver, frame

My web-app has a share on facebook link which opens a frame in the current page.
I need to activate this frame during some automated tests (webdriver, python).
This is the html at the start of the frame:

```
<div class="fb_dialog_content fb_dialog_iframe">
<iframe id="f1c1b40a973212a" class="FB_UI_Dialog" scrolling="no" name="f54b1bf38c5fe6" />
```

I cannot select this frame by name because that's different for each call.
I could not find a frame selection method by class or by xpath with webdriver python.

Answer (score 1):

Try to select the `frame` using the `frame index` value. Then too you not succeed use this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534622/selecting-an-iframe-using-python-selenium) to how to use the JavaScript in the selenium. According to python API doc it is possible to switch to the child frames using `Dot` operator. Reference from [Python API doc](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/navigating.html#popup-dialogs).

Comment: I tried the index approach, did not work. Frame was selected but element could not be found. I'm thinking now that it is probably a cross-domain permission problem.