# NoSuchElementException - Unable to locate element

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have an input box like the one I am using here to enter my question, and whose HTML is

```
<body id="tinymce" class="mce-content-body" contenteditable="true" onload="window.parent.tinymce.get('Description').fire('load');" spellcheck="false" style="padding-bottom: 50px; padding-left: 1px; padding-right: 1px; overflow-y: hidden;">
<p>
<br data-mce-bogus="1"/>
</p>
</body>
```

Every-time, I try to enter some text to it

```
@FindBy(xpath="//body[@id='tinymce']") WebElement Category_Body;
Category_Body.sendKeys("Android Smart Phone - 16GB");
```

I get the error -

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//body[@id='tinymce']"}

Comment: Make sure this element is not inside any frame or iframe??

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you are getting `NoSuchElementException` as your provided exception, There may be following reasons :-

- May be when you are going to find element, it would not be present on the `DOM`, So you should implement `WebDriverWait` to wait until element visible as below :-

  ```
  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
  WebElement Category_Body = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("tinymce")));
   Category_Body.sendKeys("Android Smart Phone - 16GB");
  ```
- May be this element is inside any `frame` or `iframe`. If it is, you need to switch that `frame` or `iframe` before finding the element as below :-

  ```
  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

  //Find frame or iframe and switch
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt("your frame id or name"));

  //Now find the element 
  WebElement Category_Body = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("tinymce")));
   Category_Body.sendKeys("Android Smart Phone - 16GB");

  //Once all your stuff done with this frame need to switch back to default
  driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
  ```

Comment: Thanks - it worked. There is a frame and after switching to the frame - I was able to enter the value to the input box.

Comment: this didn't work for me, this solution did however : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534622/selecting-an-iframe-using-python-selenium