# No such element: Unable to locate element: exception from webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've a base class where in I've defined webDriver as (using Guice). This has my beforeclass defined along with the below line of code

```
    @Inject
    protected Provider<WebDriver> webDriverProvider;

    protected static WebDriver webDriver;
```

I've another class which gets executed after beforesuite and it has a method1 where I've written my test for a given function. And it looks something like this

```
public void method1() throws InterruptedException {
       Thread.sleep(3000);
       log.info("Navigating to Method1");
       webDriver.findElement(By.xpath(Element1)).click();
    }
```

The problem here is when the line
    webDriver.findElement(By.xpath(Element1)).click();

is executed I get an exception message as org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element:

Xpath is correct. I've a dialog box before this method which is part of my beforesuite

I tried adding following lines above the click statement:

```
webDriver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

log.info(webDriver.findElement(By.xpath(Element1)).getAttribute(Element1));
         webDriver.findElement(By.xpath(Element1)).isDisplayed();

The problem is the first instance where "webDriver" is located it throws an exception as NoSuchElementException

Any pointers would help me in debugging it further.

Thanks.

Comment: I've extended class1 in class2

Comment: Follow this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39190910/nosuchelementexception-unable-to-locate-element/39191349#39191349

Comment: Saurabh: It's not in a iframe and also I've implemented wait for 10 seconds which did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If your are sure Xpath is right. You can try adding more sleep.
As you said there is dialog box then check whether it is hiding the element1