# Using Selenium Webdriver, grabbing data not showing up in innerhtml

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, innerhtml

I am trying to use selenium to grab text data from a page.

Printing the html attributes:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_id("divresults")
```

Results:

```
print(element.get_attribute('innerHTML'))

<div id="divDesktopResults"> </div>
```

Results:

```
print(element.get_attribute('outerHTML'))

<div id="divresults" data-bind="html:resultsContent"><div id="divDesktopResults"> </div></div>
```

Tried grabbing this element

Results:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span[class='glyphicon glyphicon-tasks']")


Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"span[class='glyphicon glyphicon-tasks']"}
```

This is the code when copied from the Browser. There is much more below 'divresults' that did not show up in the innerhtml printout

```
<div id="divresults" data-bind="html:resultsContent">
    <div> 
        <div class="row" style="font-size:8pt;"> 
            <a data-toggle="tooltip" style="text-decoration:underline" href="#pdfviewer?ID=D218101736">  
                <strong>D218101736 </strong>  
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-new-window"></span> 
            </a> 
        <div class="btn-group" style="font-size:8pt;margin-left:10px;" id="btnD218101736">   
            <span style="display:none;font-size:8pt;" id="lblD218101736"> Added To Cart</span> 
            <button type="button" style="font-size:8pt;" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> Add To Cart 
                <span class="caret"></span> 
            </button> 
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu"> 
                    <li> <a href="#" onclick="addToCart('D218101736', event)"><strong>Regular ($7.00)</strong></a> </li> 
                    <li> <a href="#" onclick="addToCartCertified('D218101736', event)"><strong>Certified ($12.00)</strong></a> </li> 
                </ul> 
        </div>  
    </div> <br> 

    <ul class="nav nav-tabs compact"> 
        <li class="active"> 
            <a data-toggle="tab" href="#D218101736_Doc"> 
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span>  
                <span>Doc Info</span> 
            </a> 
        </li> 
        <li class="hidden-xs"> 
            <a data-toggle="tab" href="#D218101736_Thumbnail"> 
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-large"></span>  
                <span>Thumbnail</span>
            </a> 
        </li> 
       ....
```

How to I get data beneath divresults in the instance?

Comment: maybe will help you this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39190910/nosuchelementexception-unable-to-locate-element?rq=1

Comment: There are no iframes, Im familiar with that issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that it's one of two things:

1. There is more than one element that matches that locator. To investigate this, try using `$$("#divresults")` in the dev console and make sure that it returns 1. If it returns more than one, run `$$("#divresults")[0]` and make sure the element returned is the one you want. If it is, go on to step 2. If it isn't, you will need to find a locator that is more specific. If you want our help, you will need to provide a link to the page or more of the surrounding HTML to the desired element.
2. You need to add a wait so that the contents of the element can finish loading. You could wait for a locator like `#divresults strong` or any number of locators to find some of the elements that were missing. You would wait for them to be visible (or at least present). See [the docs](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) for more info and options.

Comment: Thank you for the input. I added time.sleep(5) and that did the trick