# Successfully switching to iframe but unable to find element

Tags: python, selenium, iframe, browserstack

I am running selenium scripts using python on a variety of different sites using the same `iframe`. On some sites, I'm able to run the full code successfully, however I've come across a site where I am running the same code within the `iframe` but am getting an error that says it's unable to find the element.

I've tried different selectors but the same error persists. Keep in mind, this same code is running successfully on other sites with this same iframe.

Here is the html structure of the `iframe`:

```
<iframe class="zoid-component-frame zoid-visible" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" name="xcomponent__div_renderer__latest__pmrhk2leei5cendcgi..." title="ShopRunner Love it. Get it." scrolling="no" style="background-color: transparent;" src="https://content.shoprunner.com/components/divRenderer/index.html?env=prd&amp;uid=b9695b75b4&amp;logLevel=error&amp;version=latest&amp;xcomponent=1"></iframe>
```

Here is the structure of the button:

```
<button aria-label="Sign up free for ShopRunner." class="sr-button bn bg-transparent underline ph0" type="button" data-trigger="learnMore">Sign Up FREE</button>
```

This is the version of the code that's working on other sites:

```
    # switch to the context of the browser
    browser.switch_to.default_content()

    # wait until iframe loads and then switch to the context of the iframe
    browser.switch_to.frame(browser.find_element_by_class_name('zoid-component-frame'))

    # wait for the learn more button to be clickable and then click
    browser.find_element_by_css_selector("button[data-trigger='learnMore']").click()

    # switch to the context of the modal
    browser.switch_to.default_content()

    # pause on learn more modal (for visual inspection) and then close modal
    time.sleep(2)
    browser.find_element_by_id('sr_header_close').click()
```

These are some other selectors I've tried with the same error:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Sign Up FREE')]").click()

browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".sr-button.bn.bg-transparent.underline.ph0").click()
```

I've also tried adding a wait statement between switching to the iframe and finding the css selector and I've tried using an `ActionChain` to find the element:

```
button = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("button[data-trigger='learnMore']")
browser.implicitly_wait(10)
ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(button).click(button).perform()
```

I am expecting to be able to click on the button but am getting the following error:

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"button[data-trigger='learnMore']"}

Comment: Does iframe class name same on all sites? it looks like you are not using full class name - 'zoid-component-frame zoid-visible' while switching to iframe.

Comment: You're right, I'm only using part of the name, on the other sites it is successful, and on this one it doesn't break until after finding the iframe, there's just something preventing it from finding the element after switching to the iframe on this one that I haven't figured out yet.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are getting the exception "NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:"

You can read more on this in this link: [NoSuchElementException - Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39190910/nosuchelementexception-unable-to-locate-element)

Comment: Thanks for the link, I tried those suggestions but the error persists. Haven't been able to find out why the element can't be found here, it may be something unusual is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Try switch to `iframe` with this strategy.

Import this :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
```

And try :

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(expected_conditions.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="zoid-component-frame zoid-visible"]')))
```

For `Sign Up FREE` button, please try find by `xpath` like this :

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="sr-button bn bg-transparent underline ph0"]').click()
```

Comment: Thanks for looking at this. I tried your suggestion but the error persists.

Comment: Can you share the site url ?