# Cannot find JavaScript rendered element with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I'm a beginner in Selenium. I want to type the address in the search box. But I have a problem with finding that field. Field HTML code:

```
<input type="text" class="SearchField_SearchField__hDobT" placeholder="Address..." value="">
```

I'm trying to do something like this:

`element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='SearchField_SearchField__hDobT']")`

or

`element=driver.find_element_by_class_name("SearchField_SearchField__hDobT")`

I get that errors:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@class='SearchField_SearchField__hDobT']"}
  (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.132)
```

or

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".SearchField_SearchField__hDobT"}
  (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.132).
```

I cannot access other fields either. I render the HTML content with JavaScript.

I don't know what the problem is. Please help!

Comment: Can you access other elements on the page with Selenium? Do you render the HTML content with JavaScript?

Comment: **Can you access other elements on the page with Selenium?** - No. I have for example this field :`<input type="text" class="SearchField_SearchField__hDobT" placeholder="Something..." name="categorySearchField" value="">` and I have the same problem. **Do you render the HTML content with JavaScript?**- Yes.

Comment: Very likely the HTML element is not yet rendered by the time your Selenium script tries to access it then. You need to incorporate some waiting. See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39190910/nosuchelementexception-unable-to-locate-element?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Thanks, it works, I need to wait until element visible.