# Selenium Python : Unable to get element by id/name/css selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, selenium

For a school project, I'm trying to create a Python Script which is able to fill in different forms, from different websites.

Here is the thing, for some kinds of website, I'm not able to catch the form elements which Selenium.
E.g. in this website : http://www.top-office.com/jeu
Where I inspect the page with firefox, the input "Name" box has the id "lastname", but Selenium is not able to get it. And when I display the html code of this page, the form looks like being included from another page or something.

I tried to getelementbyid, byname, bycssselector, etc.
I also tried to wait for the page to be entirely loaded by using WebDriverWait(driver, 5), but it still do not work.

Do you have any solutions or suggestions ?

PS : Even with javascript, I'm not able to get this element by id

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element that you are trying to interact with is inside of an iframe. You need to use the `driver.switch_to_frame()` method in order to switch the driver to focus on that iframe. Only when it has switched into that iframe can it interact with its elements.

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534622/selecting-an-iframe-using-python-selenium) on how to use it. You can locate the iframe using xpath, like this: `//iframe[@src = 'https://adbx.me/grandjeuclubmed/']`. Then, you can use the code mentioned in the post I gave you.

Comment: How did you know that the element is in a frame ? I only figured that out after I saw the iFrame code `<iframe style="border: none; overflow: hidden; width: 810px; height: 850px; display: block; margin: 0 auto;" src="https://adbx.me/grandjeuclubmed/" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="320" height="240"></iframe>`

Comment: I went to the website and inspected the element in question (using Developer Tools on Chrome). It was clearly inside of an iframe.

Comment: Thanks, it helps a lot !