# How to click on an image that has a title and src

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to ask you kindly to help me out here with a basic issue.
Can't click on a image that has these 2 caracters: a title and src link.
I tried  until now with XPATH:

```
".//*[@id='resultsTable']/tbody/tr[2]/td[11]/a[2]/img"

elmlupa=browser.find_element_by_xpath('//a[img/src="/common/images/Detail.gif"]').click()

"//img[@title='details']"
```

##LATER EDIT: I used even with the XPATH from firebug/firepath:

```
#sortam dupa decision date manual
#clicuim pe prima lupa
browser.implicitly_wait(2)
browser.switch_to.default_content()
browser.switch_to.frame("main")
browser.implicitly_wait(2)
time.sleep(10)
elmlupa = browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='resultsTable']/tbody/tr[2]/td[11]/a[2]/img").click()
```

[image]

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try below line of code:

```
elmlupa=browser.find_element_by_xpath('//a[img[@title="Details"]]').click()
```

Note that `XPath` is case-sensitive: `"Details" != "details"`

Comment: Thank you @Andersson. I tried and still i receive the same error of not locating the picture of the 'loop". I tried even with the firebug/firepath XPATH and still i can't locate it. Do you know if the site have some kind of protection not to click on items? I have to say also that on the frame each row has the same loop details and maybe this creates the error? just because there are more than 20 loops with the same details on the page?

Comment: Hi, I saw that all the resuls from the table are coming into an iframe. Does this changes somehow the game? so inside the main frame, the results are populating into an iframe. I think that this is why it couldn;t find the image. What do you think?

Comment: Yes, to handle elements inside an `iframe` you should [switch to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534622/selecting-an-iframe-using-python-selenium/24286392#24286392) first. There are few possible ways how to handle `iframe`. Let me know if approach from provided link doesn't work for you

Comment: Thank you @Andrersson! it worked! i had to tweak a bit to make it like this: iframe = browser.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe")
browser.switch_to.frame(iframe).  However when trying to click on the image from the new iframe :D i receive an error like \\\\selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException:\\\\ I don't understand what is this. I think that behind that image is a java o javascript that will open a new window when clicking the image.

Comment: Can you share page `URL`?

Comment: Hi Andersson, unfortunately i can't as is privately url where i have to login etc. I located the element with xpath elmlupa = browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='resultsTable']/tbody/tr[2]/td[11]/a[2]/img").click()

Comment: hi @Andresson, no is not working. by using xpath i still receive that error. Thank you!

Comment: You'd better to open new ticket regarding new issue and add all related details

Answer (score 0):

Try below:
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//img[@title="Details" and @src="/common/images/Detail.gif"]').click()

Also, in some cases you might need to click on the  instead of an img.

Comment: Thank you @sen4ik! i did this and still have the error. I think the issue comes from the fact that there are more than 20 pictures with the same title and same src code. This can create an issue?

Comment: You can specify the index of the link you want to click image in  '//a[1]/img[@title="Details" and @src="/common/images/Detail.gif"]'

Comment: Thank you @sen4ik! i just tried and still have the same error. the image is inside of a table...don't know if this would be a an issue, or maybe the site has some kind of protection. do you know how i can see if has a protection or not?

Comment: Hi, I saw that all the resuls from the table are coming into an iframe. Does this changes somehow the game? so inside the main frame, the results are populating into an iframe. I think that this is why it couldn;t find the image. What do you think?

Comment: Yes, it does changes the game. You have to switch to iframe first. Something like driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe")).

Comment: Thank you @sen4ik! it worked! i had to tweak a bit to make it like this: iframe = browser.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe")
browser.switch_to.frame(iframe).  However when trying to click on the image from the new iframe :D i receive an error like \\\\selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException:\\\\ I don't understand what is this. Behind that image is a java o javascript that will open a new window when clicking the image.

Comment: Try to click on the link <a> tag instead of an img.