# How to switch to frameset using Python Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, frameset

I have been trying to understand how switching to a frameset works using py-selenium with no avail.

The website I am stating here is very similar to the web application that I am working on. 
https://www.quackit.com/html/tutorial/frame_example_frameset_1.html

Ideally I would like to access element-1 in this image and then move to the second frame and access element-2.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [selecting an iframe using python selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534622/selecting-an-iframe-using-python-selenium)

Comment: Thank you responding Bill Bell. However I am looking at a frameset and not iframe. I am able to move across iframes which python selenium  identifies the element as frames. But the tag frameset nor the frame src is identifed as frames.

Comment: That wasn't me. :) I looked at the HTML and could see that it includes a couple of `frame` elements. That's why I felt justified in altering the text in your question slightly.

Comment: Can you describe your issue in more details? Also share the code you've tried along with the exception log (if you get any). Note that you don't need to *switch to frameset* as `frameset` is common WebElement and should be handled appropriatelly

Comment: I am sorry Bill Bell. My bad. This is my first ever question here. And well, I was able to resolve this with some mystery. Previously when I had tried to use find_element_by_xpath to dig the frame, I was not able to, but after a couple of coffees and 2 hours, I was able to get it. :-)

Comment: Thank you Anderson but this worked !!

driver.get("https://www.quackit.com/html/tutorial/frame_example_frameset_1.html")

frame1=driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/frameset/frame[1]')

driver.switch_to_frame(frame1)

Comment: Seems you got an answer to your Question. Let me know if you are still looking out for a better option.

Comment: @Chan8211, yep this how switching to **frame** works... But in your question you ask about how to switch to **frameset**. Next time be more explicit about what exactly you want your code to do

Comment: I need a target frame of the form: `html/frameset/frameset[1]/frame[2]`, the idea of ignoring `frameset` doesn't make sense to me.  The first `frameset` does not even contain any `frames`, just other `framesets`.  Ignoring the `framesets` would be a hierarchical mistake.  Just using the frame name doesn't work either.  Please help!

Answer (score 2):

Here is one approach.

Load the initial page. Use an xpath expression to find the two `frame` elements. The, for each of them, get its url. Now you can use `driver.get` again (for each url) to load the page corresponding to the frame, and then find the `p` element that you want.

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> driver = webdriver.Chrome()
>>> driver.get('https://www.quackit.com/html/tutorial/frame_example_frameset_1.html')
>>> for frame in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//frame'):
...     frame.get_attribute('src')
...     
'https://www.quackit.com/html/tutorial/frame_example_left.html'
'https://www.quackit.com/html/tutorial/frame_example_right.html'
```

Any questions, please ask. If this does what you want, please mark the answer 'accepted' since that's the protocol on SO.

Comment: Hey Bill, this worked !!!

driver.get("quackit.com/html/tutorial/frame_example_frameset‌​_1.html") frame1=driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/frameset/frame[1]‌​') driver.switch_to_frame(frame1)

Comment: Yup, that was a possibility. I was looking for an answer as simple an answer as possible.