# Unable to locate element no such element

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://www.techfetch.com/JS/dashboard.aspx?page=fetchjobs')
time.sleep(5)
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="txtKeyword"]')
element.send_keys("Java")
```

Error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="txtKeyword"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=62.0.3202.94)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.29.461591 (62ebf098771772160f391d75e589dc567915b233),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)
```

[image]

The Screen shot displays that the xpath is correct and available

Comment: Possible duplicate of [selecting an iframe using python selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534622/selecting-an-iframe-using-python-selenium). Have a look at the top voted answer, not the accepted one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the input field you are trying to fill in is within `iframe`. First switch it and then try to do what you did earlier:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://www.techfetch.com/JS/dashboard.aspx?page=fetchjobs')
time.sleep(5)
driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_id("contentframe"))  ##switch it
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="txtKeyword"]').send_keys("Java")
```

Answer (score 0):

To send a Character Sequence to the `Keywords` Box, first we need to `wait` for the `frame` to be available to switch to it then locate the `Keywords` Box to send the Character Sequence as follows :

```
driver.get('http://www.techfetch.com/JS/dashboard.aspx?page=fetchjobs')
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(By.XPATH,"//iframe[@id='contentframe']"))
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='txtKeyword']")
element.send_keys("Java")
```