# How to click element that's contained within multiple html tags using selenium in python

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath, webautomation

I'm trying to develop a website automation using selenium webdriver on python, but i'm having trouble clicking on a certain tag.

The website I'm trying to automate is very old and contains multiple iframe and <'html'> tags, and that's giving me a hard time on finding the xpath of the element want to click.

This is the resultant xpath using the copy xpath feature of browser:

```
 /html/body/div/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/div/span[2]/div[1]/img
```

However, it appears that this xpath is only considering the last <'html'> tag the element is contained, and not all of them, and therefore it's not being able to execute the click.

I tried changing the index of the <'html'> tag, for example

```
 html[2]/body/...
```

but it didn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please mention the proper html code of the element which your trying to access.

Comment: First of all, try not to use an absolute xpath. It is very risky, especially when it is so long. A minor change in the html could break the xpath. Could you paste the html code of webpage?

Comment: If page includes iframe/frame, you need to switch to the frame firstly before find/oprerate element inside it.  Use html[index] can't resolve your problem, have to switch to frame.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [selecting an iframe using python selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534622/selecting-an-iframe-using-python-selenium)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You haven't shown us any of your code, but I bet that it fails to switch to the target frame.  With iframes, you must instruct the webdriver to switch_to to each iframe before it will find elements within the frame.  If you update your question with some of your code, I can show you where the switch_to statements might go.

Comment: You are right! Thanks! 
I switched to the frame and it worked, thanks a lot.

Comment: Pardon me if it was a stupid question haha, but I recently began programming in python and I got stuck in this problem for some time.