# Unable to click or select checkbox using selenium python webdriver chrome

Tags: python-3.x, xpath, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

After all unsuccessful tries I had to ask for the help.
The thing is I want to make script which will automatically login, go to specific tab ("WAN"), click appropriate check box (to disable NAT) and log out. (It's actually  Huawei GPON router HG8245)..

My code goes fine until the check box, so...

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoAlertPresentException
import unittest, time, re

driver=webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\chromedriver.exe") #load the driver => OK
driver.get("http://192.168.100.1") #go to this web page => OK
driver.find_element_by_id("txt_Username").send_keys("root") #username=root => OK
driver.find_element_by_id("txt_Password").send_keys("root") #password=root => OK
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='button']").click() #click Submit button => OK
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='headerTab']/ul/li[2]/div[2]").click() #Go to the 'WAN' tab => OK
```

And for the clicking of check box my tries:

```
#1
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='InternetGatewayDevice.WANDevice.1.WANConnectionDevice.2.WANPPPConnection.1']").click()  #=> NOT OK
#2
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='record_1']/td[1]/input").click() #=> NOT OK
#3
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#record_1 > td > input[name=\"rml\"]").click() #=> NOT OK
```

Of course all xpaths are checked in chrome via console (in the Mozilla as well) and they seems fine!
Any ideas how to solve this?

HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
   <body>[![enter image description here][1]][1]
      <div id="main">
      <div id="header">
      <div id="center" style="height: 495px;">
      <div id="nav" style="height: 495px;">
      <div id="content" style="height: 495px;">
      <div id="topNav">
      <div id="frameWarpContent" style="height: 470px;">
      <iframe id="frameContent" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="no" src="html/network/wan.asp" style="height: 470px;" height="100%" frameborder="0" width="100%">
      <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
      <html id="Page" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltl">
         <head>
         <body class="mainbody">
            <script language="JavaScript" src="../../resource/common/util.js?1103405">
            <script language="JavaScript" src="../../resource/english/jsdiff.js?1103405">
            <script language="JavaScript" src="../../resource/common/tabdes.js?1103405">
            <script language="javascript" src="../common/manage_mode.asp">
            <script language="javascript" src="../common/user_info.asp">
            <script language="javascript" src="../common/topo_info.asp">
            <script language="javascript" src="../common/feature_info.asp">
            <script language="javascript" src="../common/wan_prefix_acquire.asp">
            <script language="javascript" src="../common/wan_address_acquire.asp">
            <script language="javascript" src="../common/wan_dns.asp">
            <script language="javascript" src="../common/wan_list.asp">
            <script language="javascript" src="../common/wlan_list.asp">
            <script language="javascript" src="../common/lanmode_list.asp">
            <script language="javascript" src="../common/policyroute_list.asp">
            <script language="javascript" src="wan_language.html?1103405">
            <script language="javascript" src="../common/wan_pageparse.html?1103405">
            <script language="javascript" src="../common/wan_databind.html?1103405">
            <script language="javascript" src="../common/wan_control.html?1103405">
            <script language="javascript" src="../common/wan_check.html?1103405">
            <script language="JavaScript" src="../../resource/english/bbspdes.html?1103405">
            <script>
            <div id="PromptPanel">
            <script>
            <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
            <tbody>
            <tr>
            <tr>
            <td id="Wan Connection">
            <table id="wanInstTable" class="tabal_bg" width="100%" cellspacing="1">
            <tbody>
            <tr class="tabal_title">
            <tr id="record_0" class="tabal_01" onclick="selectLine(this.id);">
            <tr id="record_1" class="tabal_01" onclick="selectLine(this.id);">
            <td align="center">
            <input name="rml" value="InternetGatewayDevice.WANDevice.1.WANConnectionDevice.2.WANPPPConnection.1" onclick="" type="checkbox">
            </td>
            <td align="center">
            <td align="center">
            <td title="RealName :HSI Status :Connected IPAddress :10.10.10.10" align="center">
            </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>
            <script>
            <form id="ConfigForm">
            </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>
            </body>
            </html>
            </iframe>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div id="footer">
            <div id="fresh">
            </div>
            </body>
            </html>
```

*Edit: Modifying code tags and IP values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering provided HTML code sample you need to [switch to `iframe`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534622/selecting-an-iframe-using-python-selenium) before handling check-box:

```
driver.switch_to.frame("frameContent")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[@id='record_1']//input").click()
```

Comment: God Bless you!!! Can you please tell me how you concluded this so I can understand? Thank you!!!!

Comment: `iframe` is an HTML document rendered inside base HTML. You cannot handle elements of embedded `iframe` without switching to it. To check whether element located inside `frame`/`iframe` - just check ancestors. In your case there is `<iframe id="frameContent" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="no" src="html/network/wan.asp" style="height: 470px;" height="100%" frameborder="0" width="100%">` ancestor of target `input`

Comment: Clear! One more time BIG tnx my dear!