# How do I send text into a textarea through Selenium and Python as per the HTML

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

Cannot figure out how can I write text into a popup, here is how the pop-up looks like: [image]

```
<textarea style="position: absolute; padding: 0px; width: 1px; height: 1em; outline: currentcolor none medium;" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" tabindex="0" wrap="off"></textarea>
```

This is how I tried to access it by using XPath:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div[1]/textarea").send_keys("Some text here")
```

Getting error that element is not found on the page:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: /html/body/div/div[1]/textarea
```

I used as well **css_selector** to access element, but still same error.
How can I access popup properly?

Here is more HTML code: https://pastebin.com/6jdix2Cm

Comment: Seems like it is in iframe. can you share little bit more HTML around this `textarea`

Comment: here is more code https://pastebin.com/6jdix2Cm. Textarea is wrapped in the iframe

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Switching to iframe in selenium python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switching-to-iframe-in-selenium-python)

Comment: @Andrew : Can you give us update ? Was any one of the answer helpful ? or are you still facing any issue ?

Comment: @cruisepandey Thanks a lot it solved my problem!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select iframe using Python + Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534622/select-iframe-using-python-selenium)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per your response , that this **textarea** is in **iframe**.

First you will have to switch to frame, then you can interact with this textarea.

For switching to iframe, you can use this code :

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@src='https://qsm.qoo10.sg/gmkt.inc.gsm.web/common/scripts/module/tiny_mce_4.5.7/source/plugins/codemirror/source.html']"))
```

then you can interact with **textarea** as :

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("textarea[spellcheck='false'][wrap='off'][style$='outline: currentcolor none medium;']").send_keys("Some text here")
```

It is always good to switch to default content, once you are done with the particular iframe.For that you will need this code :

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: driver.switch_to.frame() is deprecated and driver.switch_to.defaultContent() is not a python implementation of WebDriver API

Comment: @JanRozycki : Which version of selenium are you talking about ? I have been working with selenium 3.12.0 and it works fine.

Comment: Apart from that, since when python uses camel case and semicolons? ;)

Comment: @JanRozycki , `switch_to.frame() ` is not deprecated. Deprecated one is `switch_to_frame()`

Comment: @cruisepandey use `switch_to.default_content()` instead of `switch_to.defaultContent(); `

Comment: @JanRozycki : Can't you just read what they have mentioned : `switch_to_frame(frame_reference)
Deprecated` use `driver.switch_to.frame` . Now that semi colons is a typo. Just get your facts clear before you make this kind of assumption and down voting.

Comment: @Andersson : Yeah that was just a typo, I copied it. Although I have removed the semi colon. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry for that @cruisepandey

Comment: @JanRozycki : No problem. and you see that : somebody have found those comments as useful too.  Don't make judgement too soon. Cheers !

Answer (score 0):

As per the *HTML* you have shared, as the `<textarea>` is within an `<iframe>` so you need to induce *WebDriverWait* to switch to the desired *frame* and then again induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable* before sending the character sequence and you can use the following solution:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[contains(@src,'gmkt.inc.gsm.web/common/scripts/module/tiny_mce_4.5.7/source/plugins/codemirror/source.html')]")))
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.TAG_NAME, "textarea"))).send_keys("Andrew")
```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```