# How to click on the Close icon of the popup as per the url provided through Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, iframe, webdriver, webdriverwait

I'm trying to get rid of the pop-up window showing up when first visiting this page: https://www.realestate.com.kh/buy/?listing_type=sale&categories=Condo&order_by=relevance&is_certified=1&private_seller=1#page-10

According to the html code, the id of the "x" element which I'd like Selenium to "click" is "leadpages-close-button"

[image]

So I'm trying to click on it with this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Safari()
driver.get("https://www.realestate.com.kh/buy/?listing_type=sale&categories=Condo&order_by=relevance&is_certified=1&private_seller=1#page-10")
driver.find_element_by_id("leadpages-close-button").close()
```

But it results in an error:

```
  File "Untitled.py", line 6, in <module>
    driver.find_element_by_id("leadpages-close-button")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 359, in find_element_by_id
    return self.find_element(by=By.ID, value=id_)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 966, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 320, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message:
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you tried waiting for the element to appear before clicking on it?

Comment: I visit the page for the first time in different browsers and there was no popup

Comment: You can't see the screaming man like on the image above? How strange...

Comment: Check if there’s popup on execution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To close the pop-up window showing up when first visiting the url `https://www.realestate.com.kh/buy/?listing_type=sale&categories=Condo&order_by=relevance&is_certified=1&private_seller=1#page-10` as the popup is within an `<iframe>`:

- First you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*
- Next you have to induce *WebDriverWait* again for the desired *element to be clickable*
- Finally invoke `click()` on the desired element.
- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

  options = Options()
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
  options.add_argument("--disable-extensions") 
  driver=webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://www.realestate.com.kh/buy/?listing_type=sale&categories=Condo&order_by=relevance&is_certified=1&private_seller=1#page-10")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "//iframe[contains(@src,'https://realestatekh.lpages.co/leadbox')]")))
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//form[contains(@action,'https://realestatekh.activehosted.com/proc.php')]/a[@id='leadpages-close-button']"))).click()
  ```

Browser Snapshot:

[image: realestate_com]

Answer (score 2):

That element is contained in an iframe so you will have to switch to iframe first. Try:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Safari()
driver.get("https://www.realestate.com.kh/buy/?listing_type=sale&categories=Condo&order_by=relevance&is_certified=1&private_seller=1#page-1")
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe")))
#driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe")) # OR driver.switch_to.frame(0) # switch by iframe index
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(driver.find_element_by_id("leadpages-close-button")))
driver.find_element_by_id("leadpages-close-button").click()
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Also see this: https://www.guru99.com/handling-iframes-selenium.html

Comment: Strangely, this doesn't seem to work (no error message, but the iframe doesn't go away). Is there something I'm missing regarding the id of the iframe, maybe?

Comment: @Rodolphe , this is because iframe is generated dynamically. Check [how to handle dynamic frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534622/selecting-an-iframe-using-python-selenium/48729644#48729644)

Comment: Have you tried your solution as is @theGuy? I can't make it work for me...

Comment: it does work for me, however I noticed iframe disappears from the screen if I use url with 'page-10' at the end. I was trying with 'page-1' at the end and it worked fine for me. Don't forget to add wait time as Andersson suggested. I will update my answer with what I tried. Another thing to note, I have tried it in Firefox not Safari, you may have check wait time if its still not working for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code to switch to dynamic iframe and click on Close button

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait

driver.get("https://www.realestate.com.kh/buy/?listing_type=sale&categories=Condo&order_by=relevance&is_certified=1&private_seller=1#page-10")
wait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe")))
driver.find_element_by_id("leadpages-close-button").click()
```

Comment: Still no luck. As soon as the page is loaded, it closes (when using 1 instead of 10 after "page=", it closes almost instantly). Might this have something to do with the fact that I'm using Safari?

Comment: Can you clarify little more: what *closes*: that frame with screaming man, main page, script? Share exception log

Answer (score -1):

Try :

```
driver.get("https://www.realestate.com.kh/buy/?listing_type=sale&categories=Condo&order_by=relevance&is_certified=1&private_seller=1#page-10")
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_id("leadpages-close-button").close()
```

Comment: this is not guaranteed to work. It might not sleep long enough, or it might sleep too long. There are selenium functions explicitly for waiting.