# Want to download data using selenium and python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriverwait

Hi I want to download the data from [Link](https://www.aemo.com.au/Electricity/National-Electricity-Market-NEM/Data-dashboard#price-demand)
where I want to download the data from region 'SA'. I have tried following code, where after selecting 'SA' tab I want to click on download arrow above '30 Min' tab.

```
chromedriver = "/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
driver.get('https://www.aemo.com.au/Electricity/National-Electricity-Market-NEM/Data-dashboard#price-demand')
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='au-target btn btn-default btn-lg active' and text()='SA']").click()
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-default au-target' and click.trigger='clickDownload($event)']")
button.click()
```

However it throws error

> Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:
> {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@class='au-target btn btn-default
> btn-lg active' and text()='SA']"}

You can get the xpath by visiting Link.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you are having the wrong xpath; SA button xpath: "/html/body/div/compose/div/compose[2]/div/span[1]/compose/button[4]" and download xpath: "/html/body/div/compose/div/compose[1]/div[1]/div/div/button[1]"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select iframe using Python + Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534622/select-iframe-using-python-selenium)

Answer (score 1):

Once you access the *url* `https://www.aemo.com.au/Electricity/National-Electricity-Market-NEM/Data-dashboard#price-demand` to download the required data you need to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired element with text as **SA** to be clickable.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* again for the desired element to be clickable.
- You can use the following solution:
- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  options = Options()
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
  options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get('https://www.aemo.com.au/Electricity/National-Electricity-Market-NEM/Data-dashboard#price-demand')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@class='iframe-dashboard-MTO' and@src='/aemo/apps/visualisations/elec-nem-priceanddemand.html']")))
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='au-target btn btn-default btn-lg' and contains(.,'SA')]"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='btn-group']//following::button[1]/i[@class='icon-download']"))).click()
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: aemo]

Answer (score 0):

Both buttons are located inside an iframe, so you should switch to that frame before clicking buttons:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_class_name('iframe-dashboard-MTO'))
wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='SA']"))).click()
wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'icon-download'))).click()
```