# Unable to locate element error through Selenium after copying xPath location

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, iframe, webdriverwait

Selenium, cannot locate xPath element

I'm a beginner learning Selenium, trying to build a tiny web scraper. First part is to go to the site and click button "Search By Address". I copied the xPath from Inspecting the element in Google Chrome, however, using Selenium to find the element keeps throwing a "unable to locate" error.

```
from selenium import webdriver
web_Url = 'http://hcad.org/quick-search/'
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\Users\Jaz\Documents\Python\Modules\geckodriver.exe')
driver.implicitly_wait(10) # this lets webdriver wait 10 seconds for the website to load
driver.get(web_Url)
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='s_addr']").click()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select iframe using Python + Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534622/select-iframe-using-python-selenium)

Answer (score 1):

The element you are trying to find is inside iframe. First, switch to iframe using '**driver.switchTo().frame()**' command and then try to find the element.

More details on switching to iframe is discussed in [this article](http://allselenium.info/handling-iframes-using-selenium-webdriver/).

```
from selenium import webdriver
web_Url = 'http://hcad.org/quick-search/'
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\Users\Jaz\Documents\Python\Modules\geckodriver.exe')
driver.implicitly_wait(10) # this lets webdriver wait 10 seconds for the website to load
driver.get(web_Url)
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='c-general']/iframe")
driver.switch_to_frame(element)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='s_addr']").click()
driver.switch_to_default_content()
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet. I'll have to look into iframe and studying it a bit more. I have a general understanding, thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

To `click()` on the element with text as **Search By Address** as the the desired element is within an `<iframe>` so you have to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use the following solution:

  - Code Block:

    ```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

    driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\geckodriver.exe')
    driver.get("http://hcad.org/quick-search/")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@src='https://public.hcad.org/records/quicksearch.asp']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#s_addr"))).click()
    ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: address_search]

> Here you can find a relevant discussion on [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)