# Using selenium, how do i click dropdown menu to get to login page ofhttps://www.phptravels.net/

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I have the following website that i would like to automate:
https://www.phptravels.net/

i would like to click on "My Account" to reach "register" and "login".

currently, i am doing it manually by navigating:

https://www.phptravels.net/demo/login

https://www.phptravels.net/demo/register

I am using python 3.7 for this task

I have tried locate it using Xpath, with no luck. it cannot find the items, nor click them.

```
[![<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle go-text-right"><i class="icon_set_1_icon-70 go-right"></i> My Account <b class="lightcaret mt-2 go-left"></b></a>][1]][1]
```

please see attached image for that

Comment: The page content is wrapped in an iframe: `<iframe class="full-screen-preview__frame" src="https://phptravels.net/demo" name="preview-frame" frameborder="0" noresize="noresize" data-view="fullScreenPreview" allow=</iframe>`.  Dealing with frames is a common `selenium` gotcha FWIW.  Here's a link to unofficial documentation: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html#moving-between-windows-and-frames  Good luck!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select iframe using Python + Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534622/select-iframe-using-python-selenium)

Comment: I still couldnt do it. can you please write what you meant?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "I still couldnt do it.".  If you looking for someone to write your code for you, then it looks like people have done that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To login in to Costco.com through the url `https://www.costcobusinessdelivery.com/LogonForm?URL=%2f` as the the desired elements are within an `<iframe>` so you have to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use the following solution:

  - `css_selector`:

    ```
    driver.get("https://www.phptravels.net/")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe.full-screen-preview__frame")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "nav li#li_myaccount>a"))).click()
    ```
  - `xpath`:

    ```
    driver.get("https://www.phptravels.net/")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@class='full-screen-preview__frame']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//nav//li[@id='li_myaccount']/a"))).click()
    ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: phptravels_login_menu]

Comment: Why you need xpath or css selector to identify the iframe when you can easily identify by its name? Sorry Your answer does not give any better resolution.

Comment: @KunduK Not sure what exactly you meant by _...better resolution..._, however it seems to be a beginners question. If you have any doubt on locators feel free to raise a new question with your new requirement.

Answer (score 1):

The link `My Account` is available inside an `iframe` name called `preview-frame`
To access the element you need to switch the iframe first.

Induce `WebDriverWait` and `frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it()`

Induce `WebDriverWait` and `element_to_be_clickable()`

Try below code.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver

driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.phptravels.net/")
#Switch to Iframe first
WebDriverWait(driver,15).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.NAME,"preview-frame")))
#Click on My Account
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='container']//li[@id='li_myaccount']/a[contains(.,'My Account')]"))).click()
#To Click on Login
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='container']//ul[@class='dropdown-menu']//a[contains(.,'Login')]"))).click()
```

To click on Sign UP you need to add following code.

```
#To Click on Sign Up
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='container']//ul[@class='dropdown-menu']//a[contains(.,'Sign Up')]"))).click()
```

**Browser Snapshot:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Danny

How to select an option from drop-down menu?

WebDriver provides three ways to select an option from the drop-down menu.

1. selectByIndex use

   dropdown.selectByIndex(5);
2. selectByValue

   dropdown.selectByValue("Database");
3. selectByVisibleText

   dropdown.selectByVisibleText("Database Testing");

Hope to help na kub.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have to click on my account first and then click on either login or signup by finding 2 `xpath` i.e one for my account, second for login and signup. I have no idea about python but here is the `xpath`:

1) Myaccount : `(.//li[@id='li_myaccount'])[2]/a/b`

2) Login : `(.//ul[@class='dropdown-menu']/li/a)[3]` or

signup : `(.//ul[@class='dropdown-menu']/li/a)[4]`

If you know how to use `List<>` you can get the list for login and signup option and click on it using index.

Hope it works for you. Thank you.

Comment: hi, thank you for the answer. but i cannot make it work.
it still cannot find the element.
i am trying via xpath.