# How to identify and send text to an element within an iframe?

Tags: python, selenium, iframe

I am trying to write 'eureka' in a field, and Selenium always triggers the same error: NoSuchElementException

This is the field where I am trying to get the data from:

```
<input type="text" class="standardTextField" id="rulesFilternameValue" name="rulesFilternameValue" onclick="if(typeof event !== 'undefined' &amp;&amp; event != null) {event.cancelBubble=true;}if(typeof event !== 'undefined' &amp;&amp; event != null) {event.cancelBubble=true;}" onkeypress="if (event.keyCode === 13){event.preventDefault();handleFilterRequest('rulelist', 'FILTER')}">
```

I have already tried with find_element_by_id, find_element_by_class, find_element_by_xpath and nothing.

The whole thing is inside an iFrame:

```
<iframe id="mainwindow" name="mainwindow" style="top: 54px; height: 849px;" 
src="/h2/welcomeAction.do?misc=1582634309181" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

but event find_element_by_id('mainwindow') fails

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select iframe using Python + Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534622/select-iframe-using-python-selenium)

Comment: unfortunately not: browser.switch_to.frame(browser.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe")) 
  ->   NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: iframe

Comment: you have to redirect your selenium driver to the proper frame. You said it is an iframe, which means that selenium isn't aware of it. So find the different frames available to the driver on the page and select the iframe. Then do your `find_element`

Comment: Doubt: when I do switch_to.frame(browser.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe")) I also get a NoSuchElementException

Comment: I was wrong and you were right guys. Sorry and thanks a lot for the help :-)

Answer (score 1):

As the the desired element is within an `<iframe>` so to invoke `click()` on the element you have to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use the following solution:

  - Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe#mainwindow[name='mainwindow']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.standardTextField#rulesFilternameValue"))).send_keys("eureka")
    ```
  - Using `XPATH`:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@id='mainwindow' and @name='mainwindow']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='standardTextField' and @id='rulesFilternameValue']"))).send_keys("eureka")
    ```
  - **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

    ```
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Selenium “selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException” when using Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome/47995294#47995294)
- [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)