# Python & Selenium: Unable to click A HREF in a frame

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm having issues clicking an A HREF on a website. Please see below for an inspection on the A HREF and the steps that I've tried. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

[image]

I've tried:

```
 browser.switch_to.default_content()
 frames = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name('frame')
 browser.switch_to.frame(frames[1])
 browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href,'Home')]").click()
```

and also:

```
 browser.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@href="javascript:openWorkFrame(\'/web/entry/en/websys/webArch/topPage.cgi\');"]').click()
```

Comment: can you please share your site

Comment: it's a private site. Are you looking for anything specific?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select iframe using Python + Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534622/select-iframe-using-python-selenium)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to switch to your first frame using `browser.switch_to_frame(element)` and then use below xpath to click on a link

```
frame = browser.find_element_by_name('header')
browser.switch_to_frame(frame)
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a/span").click()
browser.switch_to_default_content()
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try this XPath expression?

```py
xpath_expr = "//a/span[text() = 'Home']/.."
browser.find_element_by_xpath(xpath_expr).click()
```

Basically, find the span element with `text = "Home"`, then select its parent (the link).

Comment: i got the following message:    selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a/span[text() = 'Home']/.."}

Comment: Sorry then, I'm not familiar enough with Selenium, maybe the `frame` is getting in the way? I'd recommend creating a simplifiede test case by copying the basic structure of your DOM, and share it here so people can experiment with XPath expressions.