# For Python+Selenium scripts, how to Fetch data from a Sharepoint's Excel file?

Tags: python, excel, selenium-webdriver, sharepoint

For Python+Selenium scripts, how to Fetch data from a Sharepoint's Excel file?
Do we have to mandatorily download the File each time during the Automation Run, and fetch the data from that downloaded File?
If Yes, then how to download the excel from the Sharepoint using Python-Selenium?

Comment: would you please provide us with an update on the status of your issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can either interact with the Excel file in the browser tab or download the file and read it. Both options are fine.

The difference is that in the case of downloading the file, you will store the 'artifact' of your testing which can be attached to the report for future reference (it actually depends on your needs).

In case of Selenium, please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60856497/23182657) answer. You need to switch to the required iframe, and interact with the elements inside of the frame.

In case of file download, you will need to create some 'download manager' utility class/functions file.

The generic example steps of testing the 'download' process can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77828529/23182657)

Here are some example functions from one of my projects:

```
def get_number_of_files_in_directory(directory_path: str) -> int:
    if not os.path.exists(directory_path):
        raise RuntimeError(f"Given directory is not found: {directory_path}. Please make sure that path is valid.")
    return len(os.listdir(directory_path))


def get_list_of_files_in_directory(directory_path: str) -> List[str]:
    if not os.path.exists(directory_path):
        raise RuntimeError(f"Given directory is not found: {directory_path}. Please make sure that path is valid.")
    return os.listdir(directory_path)


def wait_for_number_of_files_in_directory(directory_path: str, expected_num_of_files: int, timeout: int = 30) -> int:
    if timeout < 1:
        timeout = 1
    cur_num = 0
    for i in range(timeout):
        cur_num = get_number_of_files_in_directory(directory_path)

        if cur_num == expected_num_of_files:
            logging.info(f"Number of files in the directory '{directory_path}' is expected: {expected_num_of_files}.")
            return cur_num
        logging.warning(
            f"Number of files in the directory '{directory_path}' is unexpected: {cur_num}/{expected_num_of_files}.")
        time.sleep(1)
    raise RuntimeError(f"Number of files in the directory '{directory_path}' is unexpected: {cur_num} "
                       f"(Expected: {expected_num_of_files}).\nTimeout {timeout} seconds reached.")


def get_list_of_last_modified_files_from_directory(directory_path: str, num_of_files: int) -> List[str]:
    if not os.path.exists(directory_path):
        raise RuntimeError(f"Given directory is not found: {directory_path}. Please make sure that path is valid.")

    files = sorted(glob.glob(os.path.join(directory_path, "*")), key=lambda x: os.path.getmtime(x), reverse=True)
    filenames = [os.path.basename(file) for file in files[:num_of_files]]

    if len(filenames) < num_of_files:
        raise RuntimeError(f"Unexpected number of files given: {num_of_files}.\nOnly {len(filenames)} files available "
                           f"in the '{directory_path}' directory.")
    return filenames


def get_last_modified_file_from_directory(directory_path: str) -> str:
    return get_list_of_last_modified_files_from_directory(directory_path, 1)[0]


def wait_for_last_modified_file_to_have_extension(directory_path: str, expected_extension: str,
                                                  timeout: int = 30) -> str:
    if timeout < 1:
        timeout = 1
    lst_file = ""
    for i in range(timeout):
        lst_file = get_last_modified_file_from_directory(directory_path)

        if lst_file.endswith(expected_extension if expected_extension.startswith(".") else ("." + expected_extension)):
            return lst_file
        time.sleep(1)
    raise RuntimeError(f"Extension of the last modified file in the directory '{directory_path}' is unexpected: "
                       f"{lst_file} (Expected: {expected_extension}).\nTimeout {timeout} seconds reached.")
```

To parse the Excel file I can suggest using [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) python library.

It is pretty easy to use (see the [tutorial](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html) section)

Comment: Hi @sashkins, 
Thanks for your reply on it. However, could you please elaborate a little on what python-selenium 'action' or code would start the download of the file from Sharepoint?

I am able to login to Sharepoint and go to that file(I can open it as well). But 
1. neither able to access any of its data once it is open, 
2. nor able to click anywhere to start the download.

The options I found onlien suggested to create API through "response = request....", like
  response = requests.get(api_endpoint, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username, password))

Comment: @user9811289, when I navigate to https://www.microsoft365.com/launch/excel , after the login I can see a list of files available to me. I can filter the required file, click 3 dots near the name, and select the 'download' option.