# Python Selenium can´t find a way to write in a form inside iframe tag

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, iframe, css-selectors

I'm trying to write some text to an element which looks like this:

[image: Pic1]

The HTML code looks like this:

[image: Pic2]

What I'am trying to do is to figure out, how it would be possible to send text in the form via Selenium.

I've tried alot of things but unfortinatly nothing works. Currently this is the code I have at the moment. I choose to use @class as an indicator of the frame as this value doesn´t change everytime the website reloads.

```
iframeDescription = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@class='ifrm']")
driver.switch_to.frame(iframeDescription)
time.sleep(2)
print(iframeDescription)

formInput = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "html")
formInput.send_keys("a random Text I wish would appear inside this Box")
```

I would appreciate some advice.

Edit: thanks for the quick answers guys, I don´t have input tho- or am I missing something? I´ve wrote "test" into the form on the website to try and locate it.

[Pic3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0Lil.png)

Comment: There is more to `html` in formInput. You may expand the `body` and check for the locator stragegy, generally it would have `input` and/or `type="text"`

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/61145753/2681662

Answer (score 0):

The element is within an [`<iframe>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447) so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52607451/7429447) for the desired *element to be clickable*.

> Note: You can't send a *character sequence* to the *`body`* tag, instead you have to locate the relevant *`<input>`* tag to send the text.

- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447):

  - Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[title='Standard']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "body input"))).send_keys("Sawa")
    ```
  - Using *XPATH*:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@title='Standard']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//body//input"))).send_keys("Sawa")
    ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
   from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
   from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
   from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)
- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. :) So the first part is working pretty well, WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//body//input"))).send_keys("Sawa") this part doesn´t work tho it times out and I guess it can´t workbecause I also don´t have an input in the html, or am I missing something? I´ll edit the main question with an other screenshot.

Comment: See the _**Note**_ part ... _You can't send a character sequence to the body tag, instead you have to locate the relevant <input> tag to send the text._ ...

Comment: yeah, i just can´t find the <input> tag, I took a screen for you guys to see. Am I really missing it? I think it should be inside html, shouldn´t it?