# Selenium is not able to find the element even though it exist

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

[It is the line of code that i am using to find the element using chrome web driver and python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUr0T.png)

[This the error that is thrown everytime when i try to run the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4170T.png)

[These are the buttons on the header bar and I am trying that my code should click the html button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmO0F.png)

[This is the html code for the efforts button which i am trying to target using selenium so that it can click here but it always says no such element found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDQJH.png)

[I have even created a seperate function to again and again find the element and sleep for 5 sec after every successful attempt until it has clicked on the element but still no luck it runs on forever without ever finding the element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpXVy.png)

[This is where i am calling the function explained in the 5th picture. Here driver is chromedriver and it keeps on repeating for 10 times with 5 sec intervals but still no luck and i am continuously watching the chrome window where driver do all the work and the page has loaded but even after it is loaded it is still not working.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScLnD.png)

[It is the beginning of entire html code from inspect element in case needed by someone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFuGR.png)

[This is the remaining HTML code with EFFORTS area selected in case needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uApUy.png)

I have even tried using shadow root but that is also not working and i am also not sure that this is a case of shadow root as i have not seen shadow root specified in html when i checked the html code.

Comment: Yowza, what are those links and photos? You should just write them as code into your question.

Comment: Sorry about that i have never asked a question before it showed an option to upload photos i thought it will show both images and there details.
I will remember it next time

Comment: Okay, you can look at this link for learning how to format posts: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element you are trying to locate is under iframe with class `iframeStyle`. First switch to that iframe to access the Efforts link.

[image]

Comment: Thanks man that helped it was the problem with iframe
Tanks for your help

Comment: One more Question can u help how do i change to the specific iframe as it does not have a id or name and i am not able to search it using xpath
it says it is not a valid xpath expression

element=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@class='iframeStyle'")

I used this line to find it using xpath to switch to this frame

Comment: Try this :  'driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))'

Comment: This link might be useful for you : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534622/select-iframe-using-python-selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534622/select-iframe-using-python-selenium)

Answer (score 0):

try below xpath using xpath contains to resolve your issue:

```
 WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
                EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(text(), 'EFFORTS')]")))
```

or

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "tmsMobileId")))
```

**Note :** please add below imports to your solution

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

If you still facing no such element exception then please check if your element is present under iframe. If so then you need to switch iframe before handling **EFFORTS** anchor tag

Comment: You posted similar answers two times. You should edit your answer instead.

Comment: Yes mistakenly done actually. I will remove old one

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/work/wipro/work/pns-database/practice/attendance_filler/fill_attendance.py", line 62, in <module>
    WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(text(), 'EFFORTS')]")))
  File "E:\work\python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 


This is the error it shows when i try ur changes
Still not working

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 

This is the error as i was not able to upload a pic to show the error i copied the entire error hope that clarifies

The code is still not working

Comment: As i mentioned in the notes section have you verified if your element present in the iframe?

Comment: would you kind enough to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) answer if your issue is resolved