# Python Selenium, help me locate an element in a website

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I want to click on "new order" icon in [mt4 web terminal](https://www.mql5.com/en/trading) using selenium module in python

This is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')
driver.get("https://www.mql5.com/en/trading")
new_order = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/a[1]/span[1]')
new_order.click()
```

And this is the error that I get:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/a[1]/span[1]"}
(Session info: chrome=86.0.4240.198)
```

What is the correct way to locate that button, I searched and found some ways to locate elements for selenium but I couldn't get any of them work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The element with tooltip as *New Order* is within an `<iframe>` so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52603847/how-to-sleep-webdriver-in-python-for-milliseconds/52607451#52607451) for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use the following [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) based [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.mql5.com/en/trading')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@id='webTerminalHost']")))
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[text()='Connect to an Account']//following-sibling::div[1]/span"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@title='New Order']/span"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: I copied the code and got no error, but the new order window wouldn't open. I added "time.sleep(10)" before the last line and then it worked. And also thanks a lot for the "Locator Strategies" link.

Comment: Could you please explain the 3rd line for me? ...Connect to an Account...

Comment: @ErfanMonemi `//div[text()='Connect to an Account']//following-sibling::div[1]/span` here we are looking for a `<div>` node which have the text **Connect to an Account**, then moving to it's following siblings and identifying the first `<div>` and in that `<div>` moving one step deeper to it's child `<span>.`

Comment: Sorry that I'm asking aother question again, But then how can I choose an option in the new order window form the symbol drop-down menu? I wrote this code:
def fast_multiselect(driver, element_id, labels):
    select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id(element_id))
    for label in labels:
        select.select_by_visible_text(label)
fast_multiselect(driver, 'symbol', "USDCAD")
and got this error:
Message: Select only works on <select> elements, not on <th>

Comment: @ErfanMonemi Can you raise a new question as per your new requirement please? Would be glad to help you out.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like your page is dealing with iframes. So while the [above answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64862967/1387701) has good practices, you also need to switch to the iframe:

```
driver.switch_to.iframe(self,frame reference)
```

Look for more details at https://www.techbeamers.com/switch-between-iframes-selenium-python/ or https://stackoverflow.com/a/24286392/1387701

Answer (score 1):

You can use a different xpath:

```
new_order = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@title="New Order"]')
```

But I would suggest By, WebDriverWait, and expected_conditions:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')
driver.get("https://www.mql5.com/en/trading")
time.sleep(5)
iframe = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//iframe[@id="webTerminalHost"]')))
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
new_order = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//a[@title="New Order"]')))
new_order.click()
```

Comment: Thank you so much.I entered the code you suggested and got this error:
...TimeoutException...
Then I changed the value 10 to 40 (I'm not sure what that is) and got the same error.
I wrote another code:
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')
driver.get("https://www.mql5.com/en/trading")
result = False
while result == False:
    try:
        new_order = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@title="New Order"]')
        new_order.click()
        result = True
    except Exception  as e: print(e)
print("done")
and I get this:
....no such element....

Comment: the 10 is the seconds the page will wait. Increase that to wait longer (as you did)

Comment: @Erfan Monemi there is an iframe but there is also a popup that will cause `ElementClickInterceptedException` that goes away after a few seconds. See the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for the update, I copied the updated code and got no error, but the new order window wouldn't open. I added "time.sleep(5)" before the last line and then it worked. Thank you so much