# Python selenium chrome unable to click login button

Tags: python, css, selenium, svg, xpath

I tried to click on those login button but fail with xpath and css.

```
<div id="WsopApp">
    <div id="PokerApp" class="">
        <div class="login-popup">
            <div class="login-services-container">
                <button class="btn-social btn-facebook" data-qaid="signInFacebook">
                    <svg stroke="currentColor" fill="currentColor" stroke-width="0" viewBox="0 0 320 512" height="1em" width="1em" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                        <path d="M279.14 288l14.22-92.66h-88.91v-60.13c0-25.35 12.42-50.06 52.24-50.06h40.42V6.26S260.43 0 225.36 0c-73.22 0-121.08 44.38-121.08 124.72v70.62H22.89V288h81.39v224h100.17V288z">
                        </path>
                    </svg>Sign in with Facebook
                </button>
                <button class="btn-social btn-google" data-qaid="signInGoogle">
                    <svg stroke="currentColor" fill="currentColor" stroke-width="0" viewBox="0 0 640 512" height="1em" width="1em" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                        <path d="M386.061 228.496c1.834 9.692 3.143 19.384 3.143 31.956C389.204 370.205 315.599 448 204.8 448c-106.084 0-192-85.915-192-192s85.916-192 192-192c51.864 0 95.083 18.859 128.611 50.292l-52.126 50.03c-14.145-13.621-39.028-29.599-76.485-29.599-65.484 0-118.92 54.221-118.92 121.277 0 67.056 53.436 121.277 118.92 121.277 75.961 0 104.513-54.745 108.965-82.773H204.8v-66.009h181.261zm185.406 6.437V179.2h-56.001v55.733h-55.733v56.001h55.733v55.733h56.001v-55.733H627.2v-56.001h-55.733z">
                        </path>
                    </svg>Sign in with Google
                </button>
                <button class="btn-social btn-one-connect" data-qaid="signInOneConnect">
                    <svg stroke="currentColor" fill="currentColor" stroke-width="0" viewBox="0 0 512 512" height="1em" width="1em" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                        <path d="M512 464c0 26.51-21.49 48-48 48H48c-26.51 0-48-21.49-48-48V200.724a48 48 0 0 1 18.387-37.776c24.913-19.529 45.501-35.365 164.2-121.511C199.412 29.17 232.797-.347 256 .003c23.198-.354 56.596 29.172 73.413 41.433 118.687 86.137 139.303 101.995 164.2 121.512A48 48 0 0 1 512 200.724V464zm-65.666-196.605c-2.563-3.728-7.7-4.595-11.339-1.907-22.845 16.873-55.462 40.705-105.582 77.079-16.825 12.266-50.21 41.781-73.413 41.43-23.211.344-56.559-29.143-73.413-41.43-50.114-36.37-82.734-60.204-105.582-77.079-3.639-2.688-8.776-1.821-11.339 1.907l-9.072 13.196a7.998 7.998 0 0 0 1.839 10.967c22.887 16.899 55.454 40.69 105.303 76.868 20.274 14.781 56.524 47.813 92.264 47.573 35.724.242 71.961-32.771 92.263-47.573 49.85-36.179 82.418-59.97 105.303-76.868a7.998 7.998 0 0 0 1.839-10.967l-9.071-13.196z">
                        </path>
                    </svg>Sign in with Email
                </button>
            </div>
```

Here my code with css

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#PokerApp > div.login-popup > div.login-services-container > button.btn-social.btn-one-connect > svg > path').click()
```

And with xpath:

```
driver.get("https://playwsop.com/play")
time.sleep(15)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@data-qaid='signInOneConnect']")
```

Here is the page:

```
https://playwsop.com/play
```

Here is my error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[@data-qaid='signInOneConnect']"}   (Session info: chrome=90.0.4430.72)
```

Comment: Can you provide a link to the page?  
What error are you getting?

Comment: @Eliyahu, Thanks for the comment, I edited my post with link and error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button you are looking for is inside `iframe` so first you have to switch into that `iframe`
You are using a wrong locators.
Use `//button[@data-qaid='signInOneConnect']` `xpath` instead.
Additionally, you are talking about the `https://playwsop.com/play` page and not `https://playwsop.com/`

Comment: Thanks for the comment, here my code and still cannot find it.
```driver.get("https://playwsop.com/play")
time.sleep(15)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@data-qaid='signInOneConnect']")```
and still get this error
```selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[@data-qaid='signInOneConnect']"}
  (Session info: chrome=90.0.4430.72)```

Comment: Sure. Because first you should land on `https://playwsop.com/`, then press the "Play Now" button.  
But there is no "Login" button on the Home page at all and no element located by the css or xpath you providd initially

Comment: Thanks, I knew, I edited my code and get directly to the https://playwsop.com/play. But still cannot. Were you able to click?

Comment: I will not open a project to debug this issue, however I see the buttons there. Which one you wanted to use?
After the page is loaded try using waitForElementToBeVisible instead of clickability.

Comment: The last button, I used python here my new code and same error:
```WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[@data-qaid='signInOneConnect']"))).click()```

Comment: I see it is inside the iframe. Try switching to the iframe first and then find the element.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534622/select-iframe-using-python-selenium

Answer (score 1):

The element you are after is inside an iframe you need to switch it first to access the element

Use `WebDriverWait()` and wait for frame available and switch.

```
wait=WebDriverWait(driver,60)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='wsop-app-container']/iframe")))
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[@data-qaid='signInOneConnect']"))).click()
```

you need to import below libraries

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```