# How to scrape span tag that is inside a iframe using Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, iframe

```
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,'//[@id="dataviscontainer"]/div/iframe')))
span_texts = [item.text for item in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('span')] 
print(span_texts)
```

My objective here is to scrape text from multiple span tags which actually are in dropdown list which is inside a iframe & the iframe does not have any name class or id so I used the XPath. After running this code I get an empty list. below are 2 span tags that has the text

```
<span class="slicerText" title="Albury (C)" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border-style: solid; border-color: rgb(96, 94, 92); border-width: 0px; font-size: 13.3333px; font-family: Arial; line-height: 17px;">Albury (C)</span>
<span class="slicerText" title="Armidale Regional (A)" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border-style: solid; border-color: rgb(96, 94, 92); border-width: 0px; font-size: 13.3333px; font-family: Arial; line-height: 17px;">Armidale Regional (A)</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should first select the iframe element in a variable then apply the selection of the spans on the variable that contains the iframe reference.

this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24286392/8445072) should help you.

Comment: I did check that answer I do not want to add text i want to scrape that text everytime I try that it gives me empty list

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"XPATH","selector":"/html/body/div[6]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/span"}     <==== getting this error that this XPATH or span class does not exist

Answer (score 0):

```
var iframe = driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe"))
driver.switchTo().frame(iframe)


WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,'//[@id="dataviscontainer"]/div/iframe')))
span_texts = [item.text for item in
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('span')] 
print(span_texts)
```

)

Comment: the space between var iframe is giving an error

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
spanText = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//span[@class='slicerText']")
for e in spanText:
    print(e.get_attribute("title"))
```