# BeautifulSoup can't get all page source sometimes

Tags: selenium, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I'm using Selenium and beautifulSoup4 for scraping. The problem is that my script sometimes 'result'is empty and sometimes no. I don't understand why it's not working sometimes. Is it a security problem in the website or RAM problem ? I have no idea

`page_source = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")`

`result= page_source.find_all('div',{'class':'pv-profile-section-pager ember-view'})`

Comment: When it does not work, do you see any error ?

Comment: no just the variable result is empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your class name can be error somewhere, you can try:

```
result= page_source.find_all('div',{'class': lambda x: x and 'pv-profile-section-pager' in x})
```

or iframe html tag can be also a problem here
[Select iframe using Python + Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534622/select-iframe-using-python-selenium)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to have some delay, cause there's no error as per OP.

put some `time.sleep(5)`

if you want to do it using Selenium, I would suggest you to have a look on `ExplicitWait` from Selenium in Python bindings.

[Python - Selenium - ExplicitWait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits)

**Sample code :**

```
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "myDynamicElement"))
    )
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: A few days ago, running the soup.find_all line correctly gave me the information I needed. However, running this now gives me an empty array []