# Element not found in Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, integration

I am completely new to python and selenium both. We are uploading the data in a web based tool       through python selenium. I am getting following error

```
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"iframe\   [data-testid='shell-content'\]"}
(Session info: chrome=115.0.5790.99); For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#no-such-element-exception
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include relevant code and explanation in detail as to what you're doing and how.

Comment: Post the HTML in question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: `<iframe>`s are a different breed.  They are not technically part of the document, and have to be "entered" before they can be traversed.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534622/select-iframe-using-python-selenium